# Threads: Retrieving then executing object from ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working with threads and need to first retrieve an object from a collection and then execute the method in that object.  I used the ArrayList.get(0) to retrieve the first element, but now how do I execute the run() method for my Runnable object that I just retrieved?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

//Instance Variables
private List<Runnable> requestQueue;

//Constructor
public MyThread() {
    requestQueue = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
}

//Methods
public void run() {
    while (!requestQueue.isEmpty()) { 
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        requestQueue.get(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you need to execute each Runnable task in sequences?

Comment: Might I suggest that something in the `java.util.concurrent` package such as `ExecutorService` could provide the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: instead of using List, you may want to use [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: @logan Yes, I'm told that ExecutorService makes life much easier, however, I'm doing this for a homework assignment and they want us to have a better understanding of threading, wait/notify, and synchronization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you queue is *not* empty you can run:

```
new Thread(requestQueue.get(0)).start();
```

BTW: You should be getting a cyclic name conflict indicating that you can't extend `Thread`. You could rename the class to, say, `MyThread`.

Also have a look at [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) as a means of abstracting many of the complexities associated with the lower-level abstractions like raw Thread.

Comment: Well, this isn't my main method, but in my main method I plan on creating the new thread.  In which case, the new operator would not be necessary here, right?

Comment: It's actually called by a different name, but I wanted it to be as general as possible.

Comment: Yes, that's fine but would suggest calling your class something other than `Thread`...

Comment: If I were to create a new Thread in myThread then what you stated would be correct, but if I intend on creating the new Thread in another class then my code in myThread would need to be `requestQueue.get(0).run();`

Comment: No. just calling `run()` does not make it a `Thread`. You need to wrap your `Runnable` objects in new `Threads` for them to be threaded.